# What is the pushout of $D^n \longleftarrow S^{n-1} \longrightarrow D^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, group-cohomology

I am trying to prove that the pushout of $D^n \longleftarrow S^{n-1} \longrightarrow D^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$. How should I progress?

Answer (score 3):

It is just the sphere $S^n$ obtained by gluing two $n$ discs by their boundaries.

Comment: How about as the pushout $D^n \bigsqcup_{S^{n-1}} D^n \simeq D^n/S^{n-1}$ and $D^n/S^{n-1} \simeq S^n$?

Comment: The embedding map $S^{n-1}\rightarrow D^n$ identifies $S^{n-1}$ with the boundary of a copy $D^n$.

Comment: What exactly is the homeomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

In response to the bounty request.

We seek a suitable quotient map $D^n\sqcup D^n\to S^n$. Map: $$\begin{align}(x,0)&\mapsto(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2})\quad\text{ on the first copy of $D^n$}\\(y,1)&\mapsto(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n,-\sqrt{1-\|y\|^2})\quad\text{ on the second copy of $D^n$}\end{align}$$This is obviously well defined and continuous; it is a map of compact Hausdorff spaces, so if it is surjective then it is a quotient map. And indeed it’s easy to see it is surjective, so we realise $S^n$ is *some* quotient of $D^n\sqcup D^n$.

Now we just need to check it’s the correct quotient. What are the fibres? Evidently this map injects for points with norm strictly less than one (no $(x,0)$ can be identified with any $(y,1)$ in these cases as the signs of their last coordinates are positive, negative) and clearly it identifies $(z,0)\sim(z,1)$ exactly when $z$ has norm one; by looking at the first $n$ coordinates you see no other identifications could be made. You can convince yourself it really does enforce the quotient relation associated to $S^n\hookrightarrow D^n$. Done!

This map is extremely geometric too. It is the northern/southern hemisphere decomposition; projection onto the first $n$ coordinates corresponds to pushing the sphere down to its equator; all we are doing is taking a disk and lifting its points, adjusting only their heights, suitably so it rests on the sphere’s surface.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151252/discussion-on-answer-by-fshrike-what-is-the-pushout-of-dn-longleftarrow-sn); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.