# What is the equivalence relation of a pushout.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, pushforward

I am thinking about the equivalence relation of the pushout here $D^n \longleftarrow S^{n-1} \longrightarrow D^n,$ is it just $i(a) = i(a)$ for all $a \in S^{n-1}$ where $i$ is the inclusion map $S^{n-1} \longrightarrow D^n,$ but this is trivially true or I am missing something? I am trying to understand exactly what quotient do we have.

Any explanation will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstractly, the pushout is a space $P$ together with $f_1,f_2\colon D^n\to P$ (one for each copy of $D^n$), such that the corresponding diagram commutes, i.e., the two maps $f_k\circ i_k\colon S^{n-1}\to P$ are the same. Moreover, for any other space $X$ together with $g_1,g_2\colon D^n\to X$ and such that $g_1\circ i_1=g_2\circ i_2$, there exists a unique $h\colon P\to X$ such that ... yada yada.

In other words, $f_1$ and $f_2$ can be expected to agree *only* on the boundary, whereas they must be able to accommodate arbitrarily differing $g_1,g_2$ at all other points of the $D^n$'s.
But this just boils down taking two copies of $D^n$ and glueing them together by identifying their boundaries $S^{n-1}$. The result can be viewed as $S^{n}$, with the given $S^{n-1}$ being the "equator" and the two copies of $D^n$ being the two closed "hemispheres".

Comment: I want a mathematical expression for the equivalence relation so that I can apply the universal property of quotient topology to the map given in the second answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625844/what-is-the-pushout-of-dn-longleftarrow-sn-1-longrightarrow-dn/4851382?noredirect=1#comment10341632_4851382